# How to loop over a series of tasks in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to unmount filesystems with the below playbook.

```
vars:
unmountlist:
  - "/DATA1"
  - "/DATA2"

tasks:
  - name: unmount
    mount:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: unmounted
    with_items:
     - "{{ unmountlist }}"
    register: output
    ignore_errors: true

  - debug:
    msg: "{{ output }}"

  - name: YE unmount persistant
    mount:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
    with_items:
     - "{{ unmountlist }}"

 - name: Lazy unmount
   command: umount -l "{{ item }}"
   when: output.changed == false
   with_items: "{{ unmountlist }}"
```

The debug section looks like this:

```
ok: [host001] => {
"msg": "error is {'msg': u'All items completed', 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'results': [{'_ansible_parsed': True, 'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'/DATA1', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'failed': True, u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'src': None, u'dump': None, u'boot': u'yes', u'fstab': None, u'passno': None, u'fstype': None, u'state': u'unmounted', u'path': u'/DATA1', u'opts': None}}, u'msg': u'Error unmounting /DATA1: umount.nfs: /DATA1: device is busy\\n'}, {'_ansible_parsed': True, 'changed': False, '_ansible_no_log': False, 'item': u'/DATA2', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'failed': True, u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'src': None, u'dump': None, u'boot': u'yes', u'fstab': None, u'passno': None, u'fstype': None, u'state': u'unmounted', u'path': u'/DATA2', u'opts': None}}, u'msg': u'Error unmounting /DATA2: umount.nfs: /DATA2: device is busy\\n'}]}"
```

I am trying to achieve the below.

1. lazy unmount the only the filesystem that returns error "device is busy". I cant see how to read the variable from above debug that contains string "device is busy" and how to unmount only the filesystem that returns this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is put the tasks in a tasks file and loop over the tasks file using `unmountlist`.

This is how your tasks file (umounts_tasks.yml) will look like - [tasks file](https://pastebin.com/raw/fR7DNqVt)

Then within your play you can use `include_tasks` to include the above tasks file and loop over it with the unmountlist. So your play will look like this - [play.yml](https://pastebin.com/raw/zySceS0u)

Let me know if this worked. :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. :)